# Docker can't resolve DNS on Google Cloud Compute

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I've setup Docker 18.09.4 on GCP Compute machine. The steps I used are from the official Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ (I used the step where you can choose to install a specific version of Docker).

I wanted to control the daemon and so I've modified /etc/docker/daemon.json to have the following content:

```
{
    "debug": true,
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" ],
    "iptables": false
}
```

Now, I tried the following commands:

1. docker run busybox nslookup google.com
2. docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 busybox nslookup google.com

Both of them gave me the error:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Then I tried to start a new nginx container with:

```
docker run --name nginx -d nginx
```

Afterwards I've connected to it:

```
docker exec -ti nginx /bin/sh
```

Inside the container I executed the below command that gave me the error:

```
apt-get update
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                  
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
```

Logs from `journalctl -fu docker`

**1. docker run busybox nslookup google.com**

```
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.731158687Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /_ping"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.732917319Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.39/containers/create"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.733295607Z" level=debug msg="form data: {\"AttachStderr\":true,\"AttachStdin\":false,\"AttachStdout\":true,\"Cmd\":[\"nslookup\",\"google.com\"],\"Domainname\":\"\",\"Entrypoint\":null,\"Env\":[],\"HostConfig\":{\"AutoRemove\":false,\"Binds\":null,\"BlkioDeviceReadBps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceReadIOps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceWriteBps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceWriteIOps\":null,\"BlkioWeight\":0,\"BlkioWeightDevice\":[],\"CapAdd\":null,\"CapDrop\":null,\"Cgroup\":\"\",\"CgroupParent\":\"\",\"ConsoleSize\":[0,0],\"ContainerIDFile\":\"\",\"CpuCount\":0,\"CpuPercent\":0,\"CpuPeriod\":0,\"CpuQuota\":0,\"CpuRealtimePeriod\":0,\"CpuRealtimeRuntime\":0,\"CpuShares\":0,\"CpusetCpus\":\"\",\"CpusetMems\":\"\",\"DeviceCgroupRules\":null,\"Devices\":[],\"DiskQuota\":0,\"Dns\":[],\"DnsOptions\":[],\"DnsSearch\":[],\"ExtraHosts\":null,\"GroupAdd\":null,\"IOMaximumBandwidth\":0,\"IOMaximumIOps\":0,\"IpcMode\":\"\",\"Isolation\":\"\",\"KernelMemory\":0,\"Links\":null,\"LogConfig\":{\"Config\":{},\"Type\":\"\"},\"MaskedPaths\":null,\"Memory\":0,\"MemoryReservation\":0,\"MemorySwap\":0,\"MemorySwappiness\":-1,\"NanoCpus\":0,\"NetworkMode\":\"default\",\"OomKillDisable\":false,\"OomScoreAdj\":0,\"PidMode\":\"\",\"PidsLimit\":0,\"PortBindings\":{},\"Privileged\":false,\"PublishAllPorts\":false,\"ReadonlyPaths\":null,\"ReadonlyRootfs\":false,\"RestartPolicy\":{\"MaximumRetryCount\":0,\"Name\":\"no\"},\"SecurityOpt\":null,\"ShmSize\":0,\"UTSMode\":\"\",\"Ulimits\":null,\"UsernsMode\":\"\",\"VolumeDriver\":\"\",\"VolumesFrom\":null},\"Hostname\":\"\",\"Image\":\"busybox\",\"Labels\":{},\"NetworkingConfig\":{\"EndpointsConfig\":{}},\"OnBuild\":null,\"OpenStdin\":false,\"StdinOnce\":false,\"Tty\":false,\"User\":\"\",\"Volumes\":{},\"WorkingDir\":\"\"}"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.798613784Z" level=debug msg="container mounted via layerStore: &{/var/lib/docker/overlay2/80485548dfcf34d534f6299414f5cf425af75eec3248c438a34902e6989e154b/merged 0x557e6de7b4a0 0x557e6de7b4a0}"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.839092703Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.39/containers/9a648ee0a53651276dd1ade67d8571ab2d9a0e050bceffcb1f65fd477b767151/attach?stderr=1&stdout=1&stream=1"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.839340015Z" level=debug msg="attach: stderr: begin"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.839353672Z" level=debug msg="attach: stdout: begin"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.839814620Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.39/containers/9a648ee0a53651276dd1ade67d8571ab2d9a0e050bceffcb1f65fd477b767151/wait?condition=next-exit"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.842434668Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.39/containers/9a648ee0a53651276dd1ade67d8571ab2d9a0e050bceffcb1f65fd477b767151/start"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.843777399Z" level=debug msg="container mounted via layerStore: &{/var/lib/docker/overlay2/80485548dfcf34d534f6299414f5cf425af75eec3248c438a34902e6989e154b/merged 0x557e6de7b4a0 0x557e6de7b4a0}"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.844336549Z" level=debug msg="Assigning addresses for endpoint stoic_saha's interface on network bridge"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.844563290Z" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, <nil>, map[])"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.844618426Z" level=debug msg="Request address PoolID:172.17.0.0/16 App: ipam/default/data, ID: LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, DBIndex: 0x0, Bits: 65536, Unselected: 65532, Sequence: (0xe0000000, 1)->(0x0, 2046)->(0x1, 1)->end Curr:3 Serial:false PrefAddress:<nil> "
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.865286605Z" level=debug msg="Assigning addresses for endpoint stoic_saha's interface on network bridge"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.871127111Z" level=debug msg="Programming external connectivity on endpoint stoic_saha (74ce5214f6718a6acf89fa4e51049ded4afee75fbc8201fceed460a71a60cbfa)"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.872870334Z" level=debug msg="EnableService 9a648ee0a53651276dd1ade67d8571ab2d9a0e050bceffcb1f65fd477b767151 START"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.872898104Z" level=debug msg="EnableService 9a648ee0a53651276dd1ade67d8571ab2d9a0e050bceffcb1f65fd477b767151 DONE"
Sep 30 13:42:36 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:36.877297601Z" level=debug msg="bundle dir created" bundle=/var/run/docker/containerd/9a648ee0a53651276dd1ade67d8571ab2d9a0e050bceffcb1f65fd477b767151 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby root=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/80485548dfcf34d534f6299414f5cf425af75eec3248c438a34902e6989e154b/merged
Sep 30 13:42:37 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:37.200006747Z" level=debug msg="sandbox set key processing took 132.698845ms for container 9a648ee0a53651276dd1ade67d8571ab2d9a0e050bceffcb1f65fd477b767151"
Sep 30 13:42:37 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:37.557948653Z" level=debug msg=event module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/create
Sep 30 13:42:37 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:37.603537357Z" level=debug msg=event module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/start
Sep 30 13:42:47 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:47.697939023Z" level=debug msg=event module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/exit
Sep 30 13:42:47 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:47.754722408Z" level=debug msg="attach: stdout: end"
Sep 30 13:42:47 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:47.754721080Z" level=debug msg=event module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete
Sep 30 13:42:47 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:47.754788145Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Sep 30 13:42:47 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:47.754744392Z" level=debug msg="attach: stderr: end"
Sep 30 13:42:47 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:47.754822522Z" level=debug msg="attach done"
Sep 30 13:42:47 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:47.755246346Z" level=debug msg="Revoking external connectivity on endpoint stoic_saha (74ce5214f6718a6acf89fa4e51049ded4afee75fbc8201fceed460a71a60cbfa)"
Sep 30 13:42:47 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:47.756329538Z" level=debug msg="DeleteConntrackEntries purged ipv4:0, ipv6:0"
Sep 30 13:42:47 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:47.858389201Z" level=debug msg="Releasing addresses for endpoint stoic_saha's interface on network bridge"
Sep 30 13:42:47 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:47.858447908Z" level=debug msg="ReleaseAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.3)"
Sep 30 13:42:47 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:42:47.858487071Z" level=debug msg="Released address PoolID:LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, Address:172.17.0.3 Sequence:App: ipam/default/data, ID: LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, DBIndex: 0x0, Bits: 65536, Unselected: 65531, Sequence: (0xf0000000, 1)->(0x0, 2046)->(0x1, 1)->end Curr:4"
```

**2. docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 busybox nslookup google.com**

```
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.687551598Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /_ping"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.689067144Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.39/containers/create"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.689449247Z" level=debug msg="form data: {\"AttachStderr\":true,\"AttachStdin\":false,\"AttachStdout\":true,\"Cmd\":[\"nslookup\",\"google.com\"],\"Domainname\":\"\",\"Entrypoint\":null,\"Env\":[],\"HostConfig\":{\"AutoRemove\":false,\"Binds\":null,\"BlkioDeviceReadBps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceReadIOps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceWriteBps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceWriteIOps\":null,\"BlkioWeight\":0,\"BlkioWeightDevice\":[],\"CapAdd\":null,\"CapDrop\":null,\"Cgroup\":\"\",\"CgroupParent\":\"\",\"ConsoleSize\":[0,0],\"ContainerIDFile\":\"\",\"CpuCount\":0,\"CpuPercent\":0,\"CpuPeriod\":0,\"CpuQuota\":0,\"CpuRealtimePeriod\":0,\"CpuRealtimeRuntime\":0,\"CpuShares\":0,\"CpusetCpus\":\"\",\"CpusetMems\":\"\",\"DeviceCgroupRules\":null,\"Devices\":[],\"DiskQuota\":0,\"Dns\":[\"8.8.8.8\"],\"DnsOptions\":[],\"DnsSearch\":[],\"ExtraHosts\":null,\"GroupAdd\":null,\"IOMaximumBandwidth\":0,\"IOMaximumIOps\":0,\"IpcMode\":\"\",\"Isolation\":\"\",\"KernelMemory\":0,\"Links\":null,\"LogConfig\":{\"Config\":{},\"Type\":\"\"},\"MaskedPaths\":null,\"Memory\":0,\"MemoryReservation\":0,\"MemorySwap\":0,\"MemorySwappiness\":-1,\"NanoCpus\":0,\"NetworkMode\":\"default\",\"OomKillDisable\":false,\"OomScoreAdj\":0,\"PidMode\":\"\",\"PidsLimit\":0,\"PortBindings\":{},\"Privileged\":false,\"PublishAllPorts\":false,\"ReadonlyPaths\":null,\"ReadonlyRootfs\":false,\"RestartPolicy\":{\"MaximumRetryCount\":0,\"Name\":\"no\"},\"SecurityOpt\":null,\"ShmSize\":0,\"UTSMode\":\"\",\"Ulimits\":null,\"UsernsMode\":\"\",\"VolumeDriver\":\"\",\"VolumesFrom\":null},\"Hostname\":\"\",\"Image\":\"busybox\",\"Labels\":{},\"NetworkingConfig\":{\"EndpointsConfig\":{}},\"OnBuild\":null,\"OpenStdin\":false,\"StdinOnce\":false,\"Tty\":false,\"User\":\"\",\"Volumes\":{},\"WorkingDir\":\"\"}"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.753539217Z" level=debug msg="container mounted via layerStore: &{/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7733a25fd22c0c446c3efc0d4a42c2b57a1b596777809070d85f0162aae28272/merged 0x557e6de7b4a0 0x557e6de7b4a0}"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.787264168Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.39/containers/02a8e8580e8b9c7a37af93a19195fb5e8725c545bae0e9d384119bf0811a4e32/attach?stderr=1&stdout=1&stream=1"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.787568195Z" level=debug msg="attach: stderr: begin"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.787571115Z" level=debug msg="attach: stdout: begin"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.788642046Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.39/containers/02a8e8580e8b9c7a37af93a19195fb5e8725c545bae0e9d384119bf0811a4e32/wait?condition=next-exit"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.790059040Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.39/containers/02a8e8580e8b9c7a37af93a19195fb5e8725c545bae0e9d384119bf0811a4e32/start"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.791398955Z" level=debug msg="container mounted via layerStore: &{/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7733a25fd22c0c446c3efc0d4a42c2b57a1b596777809070d85f0162aae28272/merged 0x557e6de7b4a0 0x557e6de7b4a0}"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.791909253Z" level=debug msg="Assigning addresses for endpoint wizardly_mirzakhani's interface on network bridge"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.791990693Z" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, <nil>, map[])"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.792044255Z" level=debug msg="Request address PoolID:172.17.0.0/16 App: ipam/default/data, ID: LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, DBIndex: 0x0, Bits: 65536, Unselected: 65532, Sequence: (0xe0000000, 1)->(0x0, 2046)->(0x1, 1)->end Curr:4 Serial:false PrefAddress:<nil> "
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.802706733Z" level=debug msg="Assigning addresses for endpoint wizardly_mirzakhani's interface on network bridge"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.809600746Z" level=debug msg="Programming external connectivity on endpoint wizardly_mirzakhani (a2cbcc3a67d08696c136487ba80e40c688bd62ad99f6dffaba3a24fe050f835d)"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.811874045Z" level=debug msg="EnableService 02a8e8580e8b9c7a37af93a19195fb5e8725c545bae0e9d384119bf0811a4e32 START"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.811913727Z" level=debug msg="EnableService 02a8e8580e8b9c7a37af93a19195fb5e8725c545bae0e9d384119bf0811a4e32 DONE"
Sep 30 13:46:52 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:52.818043209Z" level=debug msg="bundle dir created" bundle=/var/run/docker/containerd/02a8e8580e8b9c7a37af93a19195fb5e8725c545bae0e9d384119bf0811a4e32 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby root=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7733a25fd22c0c446c3efc0d4a42c2b57a1b596777809070d85f0162aae28272/merged
Sep 30 13:46:53 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:53.071556709Z" level=debug msg="sandbox set key processing took 102.179237ms for container 02a8e8580e8b9c7a37af93a19195fb5e8725c545bae0e9d384119bf0811a4e32"
Sep 30 13:46:53 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:53.436036670Z" level=debug msg=event module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/create
Sep 30 13:46:53 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:53.482103873Z" level=debug msg=event module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/start
Sep 30 13:46:58 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:58.564159088Z" level=debug msg=event module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/exit
Sep 30 13:46:58 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:58.619382304Z" level=debug msg=event module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete
Sep 30 13:46:58 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:58.619428265Z" level=debug msg="attach: stdout: end"
Sep 30 13:46:58 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:58.619432344Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Sep 30 13:46:58 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:58.619436885Z" level=debug msg="attach: stderr: end"
Sep 30 13:46:58 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:58.619478361Z" level=debug msg="attach done"
Sep 30 13:46:58 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:58.620136579Z" level=debug msg="Revoking external connectivity on endpoint wizardly_mirzakhani (a2cbcc3a67d08696c136487ba80e40c688bd62ad99f6dffaba3a24fe050f835d)"
Sep 30 13:46:58 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:58.621288893Z" level=debug msg="DeleteConntrackEntries purged ipv4:0, ipv6:0"
Sep 30 13:46:58 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:58.714409171Z" level=debug msg="Releasing addresses for endpoint wizardly_mirzakhani's interface on network bridge"
Sep 30 13:46:58 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:58.714475035Z" level=debug msg="ReleaseAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.3)"
Sep 30 13:46:58 my-host dockerd[31794]: time="2019-09-30T13:46:58.714525792Z" level=debug msg="Released address PoolID:LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, Address:172.17.0.3 Sequence:App: ipam/default/data, ID: LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, DBIndex: 0x0, Bits: 65536, Unselected: 65531, Sequence: (0xf0000000, 1)->(0x0, 2046)->(0x1, 1)->end Curr:4"
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you manually install and setup Docker or are you using one of the Google container operating systems?

Comment: @JohnHanley I did manual installation for Docker. I am not familiar with Google container operating systems.

Comment: Edit your question with details on how you installed and configured Docker. Include logs that show errors with Docker and Docker networking.

Comment: @JohnHanley here you go. I've edited my question with the steps I used and logs from Docker service

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your issue on GCP with an Ubuntu 18.04, seeing that the Docker documentation you followed is based on Ubuntu and could make it work:

### **Instance installation on GCP**

- In GCP Console, I have created an instance with the image “Ubuntu 18.04”. You can specify the image under the “Boot Disk” category. By default, the image selected is going to be Debian 9, make sure to change it. You can leave all the other settings on default.
- Create instance and SSH into the instance.

### **Docker Installation on Ubuntu 18.04**

1. Now on installing Docker, I followed the same documentation you provided:
   https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu
2. Set up the repository. Make sure you install all the necessary packages indicated on the guide. You can verify if all of them have been installed with:

```
    $ dpkg -l apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
```

3. Add Docker’s official GPG as mentioned.

```
    $ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

4. Don’t forget to add the repository:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

5. Now to install the version 5:18.09.4:

```
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:18.09.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic docker-ce-cli=5:18.09.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic containerd.io
```

6. Verify it works:

```
    $ sudo docker run hello-world
```

### **DNS Resolution inside Docker with Busybox**

1. I tried to replicated your same error but received a "No answer" error instead:

```
    $ sudo docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 busybox nslookup google.com
    Server:         8.8.8.8
    Address:        8.8.8.8:53

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:   google.com
    Address: 216.58.206.14

    *** Can't find google.com: No answer
```

2. Typing "**busybox**" uses the latest version of the image available. Instead, I have tried with a different version and it worked fine:

```
    $ sudo docker run busybox:glibc nslookup google.com
    Server:         169.254.169.254
    Address:        169.254.169.254:53

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:   google.com
    Address: 216.58.208.46

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:   google.com
    Address: 2a00:1450:4001:81d::200e
```

```
    $ sudo docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 busybox:glibc nslookup google.com
    Server:         8.8.8.8
    Address:        8.8.8.8:53

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:   google.com
    Address: 172.217.16.174

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:   google.com
    Address: 2a00:1450:4001:821::200e
```

3. So I think we can confirm it was an issue with the image version. You can find more information about the image on the following link: 
   https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox?tab=description

Hope this has resolved some of your doubts.

Kind regards,

Comment: Thanks for trying out the steps. However, the purpose is to find out if it's something wrong with the network, not necessarily to make busybox image work. I want to use the VM as a node in a Docker Swarm setup and this was a step to debug this. 
As information, I already tried to add the VM to a Docker Swarm (it is added correctly), but whenever I try to run any service I am having the issues described above. I mention that all the ports were opened as described here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts

Comment: @angheladrian Following the docker installing guide for Ubuntu, I could run all of your commands without issues. I could even perform the "apt-get update" within the nginx. Could you give more details on what are you trying to accomplish and what issues are you encountering? Also update them on the main question if possible. Thanks!

Comment: @angheladrian forgot to ask if this issues are also occurring outside the busybox/nginx containers. Does the network works normally on the instance?

Comment: Yes. The network works correctly on the instance/node.